# How can I find the businesses reviewed by users with 100 or more fans?

Tags: sql, sqlite, yelp

This is from a Coursera course I am working on. This question is not necessary to complete the assignment, it is something extra I was working on to enhance my own skills. The ER diagram is:

[image: Yelp database ER diagram]

I want to see how the type of user that reviews a business effects whether or not it is open. The "review" table is connected to the "business" table and the "user" table. I want to see if a business has reviews from users that have 100 or more fans. This is the query I came up with:

```
SELECT
b.name AS [Business]
,COUNT(r.id) AS [Num Reviews]
,b.is_open [Is Open]
FROM review r
  INNER JOIN business b ON r.business_id = b.id
  INNER JOIN user u ON r.user_id = u.id
WHERE r.user_id IN (SELECT
                    u.id
                    FROM user u
                    WHERE fans > 100
                    )
```

But it returns an empty table. I think the issue might be in the last line where maybe it's looking to see if the user_id's for *all* of the reviews for a business are in the list instead of checking to see if just one is. Any help would be appreciated, it seems like a pretty complex query and I am new to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The review table links a business with a user.
Each entry in the review tables, says that user has reviwed a business.

You got fans in the user table, so looks like you need to filter only those users who have a fans >100 so just add it to the where clause

```
  SELECT b.name AS [Business]
         ,r.id         
         ,b.is_open [Is Open]
    FROM review r
    JOIN business b 
      ON r.business_id = b.id
    JOIN user u 
      ON r.user_id = u.id
  WHERE r.fans > 100
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of fans are in the User table. Business_id and User_id are foreign keys in the Review table which makes it easy to access both the User table and the Business table.

`select business.business_id, review.r_id, business.b_is_open 
 from business,review, user 
 where business.business_id = review.business_id and review.user_id = user.user_id  and user.fans>100`